# MBPRO wont start up

Tags: macos

![image capture from MBPro17 screen][1]

Help guys,

I really need a fix here. My MacBook Pro 17" keeps shutting down in booting up process. I did a "command-V" key and this what showed. Hoping this can help those of you that read this stuff.

Comment: fix that image (fast)

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about your computer, courtesy of that broken image, but if your MBP is from 2011, you may have a rather famous graphics card problem. A problem so famous, in fact, that [Apple's fixing it for free](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)! Check out that link to Apple's repair program page and see if it sounds like what's going on with your MBP.